# how to compare entered text against a string in terms of a password to trigger a new segue

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a application that is running and has segues that have questions on them and passes the data from one segue to another.

I need to add a password to my final button that triggers the the event of passing the data to the last view controller and showing the data to the person that holds the password.

I have the code that passes the code to the last page and I have the code that passes the alert to the user to enter the password.

my issue is if I have the thing for the segue before the alert the page loads and it doesn't matter if the pass word is entered or not. if the thing for the segue is after the alert nothing happens no matter what's entered in the text box.

```
@IBAction func DataReveal(_ sender: UIButton)
{
     ID = ID2.text
     date = date2.text
     Answer1 = answ1.text
     Answer2 = answ2.text
     switch sender.tag
     {
     case 1: send = "Thanks"
     default: print("No Selection")
     }
     let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password check", message: "Enter Password to see collected data", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField
        {
            textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Password"
            textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        }
        let confirmActionBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
        {
            [weak alertController] _ in
            guard let alertController = alertController, let textField = alertController.textFields?.first else
            {
                return
            }
            print("Password is \(String(describing: textField.text))")

            //Just compare Entered String in textfield with your original password password
            //if password is matched push or segue your required controller
        }
        alertController.addAction(confirmActionBtn)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Link6", sender: self)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "Link6", let destination = segue.destination as? DataviewController
        {
            destination.Answer2 = self.Answer2
            destination.Answer1 = self.Answer1
            destination.ID = self.ID
            destination.date = self.date
            destination.send = self.send
        }
    }
```

I've made the changes as mentioned in one of the answers that was provided, I've tried to run the code but there is still another issue because its still not comparing the textfield to the password string variable and when the password is entered there isn't any perform segue movement.

```
 @IBAction func DataReveal(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        ID = ID2.text
        date = date2.text
        Answer1 = answ1.text
        Answer2 = answ2.text
        switch sender.tag
        {
        case 1: send = "current data collected"
        default: print("No Selection")
        }
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password check", message: "Enter Password to see collected data", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField
        {
            textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Password"
            textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        }
        let confirmActionBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
        {
            [weak alertController] _ in
            guard let alertController = alertController, let textField = alertController.textFields?.first else
            {
                return
            }
            print("Password is \(String(describing: textField.text))")
            func performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool
            {
                if identifier == "Link6"
                {
                    if (textField.text == self.password)
                    {
                        return true
                    }
                }
                return false
            }
        }
        alertController.addAction(confirmActionBtn)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Link6", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "Link6", let destination = segue.destination as? DataviewController
        {
            destination.Answer2 = self.Answer2
            destination.Answer1 = self.Answer1
            destination.ID = self.ID
            destination.date = self.date
            destination.send = self.send
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is done in the shouldPerformSegue method.

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    if identifier == "FirstToUsersSegue" {
        if (userText.text == username && passText.text == password) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: ive added the code that you have provided im getting an error on passText.text

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to use `shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`. That method is typically used to prevent a segue from firing after it's already been triggered. For example, you might have a button that triggers a segue but may want to prevent it from firing for some reason. Since you have full control over when the segue is triggered, you shouldn't need to implement this method.

Comment: how would you go about implementing this

Comment: It's an example, you're gonna have to use your own Identifiers and variables on it. But the logic is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Alerts are asynchronous, as is performing segues, so this code is performing a segue *and* displaying an alert.

If you don't want to perform the segue until after the alert has been dismissed, you will need to put the call to `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` inside of the `confirmActionBtn` handler.

Comment: yeah, ive added the code inside the confirm, im just getting an error on the passText.text that the guy provided before

Comment: do you know of a way to implement this